# PyCharm project disappears from project tool window

Tags: pycharm, ide

The problem is - I create a new project, I have it in the project tool window, some seconds later the window changes - by its own - the project folder disappears and the main.py file is automatically closed. I have hot keys instead on the screen ("Search everywhere...", "go to file..." etc.) And I can not restore the project or open its files.
How shall I fix this?